# tinder state machine - working with lists

Tags: kotlin, state-machine

Im trying to implement state machine with some complicated business logic

I'm holding a list of objects that I need to iterate and send each object to the state machine

```
sealed class State {
    object PendingForAction: State()
    object ActionFailed : State()
    object ActionCompleted : State()
    object PendingNextAction : State()


}

sealed class Event() {

    object OnPendingForAction : Event()
    object OnActionFailed : Event()
    object OnActionCompleted : Event()

}

sealed class SideEffect() {
    object UpdateStatusPendingForAction : SideEffect()
    object UpdateStatusActionFailed : SideEffect()
    object UpdateStatusCompleted : SideEffect()
}

@Component
class StateMachine @Autowired constructor(

) {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var repository: SomeRepository
    val stateMachine = StateMachine.create<State, Event, SideEffect> {
        initialState(State.PendingForAction)
        state<State.PendingForAction> {
            on<Event.OnActionFailed> {
                transitionTo(State.ActionFailed, SideEffect.UpdateStatusActionFailed)
            }
            on<Event.ActionCompleted> {
                transitionTo(State.PendingNextAction, SideEffect.UpdateStatusCompleted)
            }
            
            // so on with next actions
        }
        onTransition() {
            val validTransition = it as? StateMachine.Transition.Valid ?: return@onTransition
            when (validTransition.sideEffect) {
                SideEffect.UpdateStatusPendingForAction -> {
                    //here i want to do complicated code that use the data object from the list
                    //but i can't access it
                }
                
                // and so on ...

            }
        }

    }
}
```

now trigger somehow the state machine with my data:

```
val data = listOf(obj,obj,obj...)
// each object is in a different state and I want it to be generic enough to know the 
state and perform the transition automatically

data.forEach{



stateMachine.transition(it)

}
```

please note that transition function only accept sideEffect but i want it to accept the object and it's state